# Principle of causality and Laplace's domain

Tags: education

what are the conditions in the Laplace's domain which ensure the causality of a system? I would be grateful if you recommend me also references. My professor said that the degree of the denominator must be greater than the degree of numerator of the transfer function. Why?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you understand what causality is?

Comment: @Andy aka In general yes, but in Laplace's domain no.

Comment: Laplace's domain is mathematics, not electronics. Maybe the mods should migrate this to Math.SE

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, if the phase of the denominator is less than the phase of the numerator you would have more zeros than poles, so the "missing poles" would be at infinity.

Comment: "missing poles" - who said anything about missing poles. Also, can you be clearer about your use of the word "phase"?

Comment: If you have more zeros than poles, the limit for s -> infinity is infinite. So you have a pole at infinity. When you do the Laplace transform, you have to check the "abscissa of convergence". In this case, infinity is at the left of this value and the Laplace transform does not exists in that point. Sorry I said phase because in italian we call the argument or angle in this way

Comment: I don't follow you. If you have more zeroes than poles, why should that scenario naturally produce a pole at infinity?

Comment: Please search on Wikipedia "pole (complex analysis)" .

Comment: It might be an idea to try and help me and no-doubt the guy asking the question a bit more. I don't see how the OP's question is serviced by this answer. His question is clear enough but your answer is not. If I'm having problems understanding what you say then possibly the guy asking the question is.

Comment: I have no more time to answer you, but i found this that can help: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e102/lectures/Laplace_Transform/node7.html

Comment: As you see, that pole at infinity make your system not causal. The answer for your question comes from complex analysis, a pole is a value for z that makes the function go to infinity, and if you have more zeros than poles, and calculate the limit for infinity, you get infinity. So infinity is a pole. I don't know what theorem affirms this! But it is in this way, it's right...